# Why can't INDIRECT() take a dynamic array reference just after opening a file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a formula containing INDIRECT() pointing to some range -- call it B4:F8.

If I specify the range explicitly, like this:

`=INDIRECT("B4:F8")`

then it works fine.

However, if the range in question is actually a *dynamic array*, of unknown size but anchored at B4, and I use the # spill operator to specify it, like this:

`=INDIRECT("B4#")`

then it still works fine, ***except just after opening the file***. On first opening the file, the formula returns #REF. However, to make it work all I have to do is force a recalc, by hitting F9 or even just putting my cursor in an empty cell and hitting Return.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Here's a screenshot of an example, shown just after opening and before hitting F9.
[image: Here's a screenshot of an example.]
The formulae above each table show the contents of B4, H4, and N4 respectively.

Comment: Perhaps it's just the order in which excel is running them. One theoretical bandaid is creating a VBA macro that will re-run the formulas after excel has been opened. (ie, macro for F9 key press).

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Make sure you run the latest version. If the issue still exists, report it to Microsoft

Comment: On my machine, the #REF! error displays for a fraction of a second, but is then replaced with the correct entries without any user intervention required.

Comment: Also, I was able to replicate your issue on my machine, too. I'm using MS-365 on a PC.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot properly replicate your issue, but I can see it happening, then taking care of itself.

Upon opening, the cell in question flashes a REF error then clearly has another calculation pass performed and replaces that with the proper result.

I think your version could well be doing all but that last step. Excel often updates versions and small, very small, things are changed.

An example of what I mean is that the last time I used a `HYPERLINK` formula, at least six months ago, but less than a year, if I clicked on whitespace in the cell (which I could increase by widening the cell), I selected the cell, no activating of the hyperlink.

I could make the whole cell "clickable" by choosing several of the various horizontal alignment options.

And yesterday/early this morning, I found that now the entire cell is selectable without any consideration of the horizontal alignment chosen.

A very small thing, one I actually consider a loss, though a small one, but something MS clearly felt needed changed to this once they heard about it happening. So they changed it. (I'm assuming because it wasn't hard to do so, so could be done easily and quickly.)

This seems like the same kind of thing. Something they did not realize happened, and presumably do not want taking place. (Nor do you, I'm thinking!) And perhaps it was quick and easy to change, so they did. Not being a huge issue, even though it'd've affected a few hundred million users, so no ballyhoo about it.

To test that... I am using the desktop version they keep as current as my loser IT provider allows, currently version 2205 (so at least a month behind). If you're using the updating version of the desktop program, and have not reached that update, it might be exactly the above. If you are past that update, or using a different version of the program, "different" like mine and "Excel On The Web" are different, not like versions 2205 and 2201 are different, then it may or may not be what is happening.

If it seems like it is, being sure you have the most recent version might well solve the issue for you. It surely would be a problem in some cases, though most times it arises, it would seem likeliest something would trigger a second calculation pass before one utilized anything in the workbook for a decision of any kind. "Likeliest" is not "always" though... Whatever program "cousin" you are using though, this seems like something detrimental to dynamic range functionality so it seems to me likely MS would push for a solution fast and update each as early as possible.

Lastly, I do not know that my program cousin ever had the issue, just that I can see the steps flashing before me and can believe it did exist here too, just never noticed by me, and is now fixed. But still, that's just "believe" and not a certainty.

In the meantime, `Isolated`'s comment has a very easy to implement fix, that of a macro, an "On Open" macro, immediately performing another calculation pass. Downside is that some organizations don't like macros and some users are leery of them regardless.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm actually on the Beta release channel, but I've seen this issue before -- from at least the beginning of the year -- well prior to switching to Beta. Oh, and I'm seeing this on both Mac and Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an indirect circular reference, which is when
a formula indirectly refers to its own cell through other cells and
formulas.

To find if this is the case :

- On the Formulas tab, in the Formula Auditing group, click the
  down-arrow next to "Error Checking"
- Click Circular References
- Excel will show the cell address of one circular reference
- The last stage is to fix the reference so it's no longer circular.

Reference :
[Circular Reference in Excel](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/circular-reference.html).

Comment: Thanks, but no I'm sure it's not that. I've actually simplified my question to remove any extraneous details, and added an example screenshot. As far as I can see, the only thing at play is the use of the # spill operator.

Comment: It looks like you're using a cell that uses a formula that gives an error because it wasn't calculated yet. The second time the value existed so the formula succeeded. Such bad order in calculation normally means a circle.

Comment: I don't see how that can be so. In my example, B4 contains =SEQUENCE(5,5) to give a 5x5 dynamic array; and N4 contains =INDIRECT("B4#"), referring to that same array via the # spill operator. So B4 has no precedents, and N4 has only one -- B4# itself (albeit via INDIRECT). There is simply no scope for circularity.